# Can anyone see a mistake in this code?

Tags: r

I'm trying to make some plots of distributions in R and i have the code but it just won't run, it says there's an unexpected symbol.

```
curve(dexp(x, rate=3) xlim=c(0,40), main="exp(rate=3) population          
 distribution", xlab="X", ylab="f(x)")
```

Im trying to plot an exponential random variable with rate 3.

Comment: Read your error message - `Error: unexpected symbol in "curve(dexp(x, rate=3) xlim"`.  The error in your code occurred somewhere inside the quoted part `"curve(dexp(x, rate=3) xlim"`, usually toward the end.  Pretty straightforward from there.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma between `dexp(x, rate=3)` and `xlim=c(0,40)`

```
curve(dexp(x, rate=3), xlim=c(0,40), main="exp(rate=3) population          
 distribution", xlab="X", ylab="f(x)")
```